# Basic coordinates conversions

Tags: go, math, coordinates, formula

I'm writing a library that can convert any type of coordinate into another.

I'm writing it in Go. I'm testing the conversions by converting coordinates into one type and then converting back to the initial type. Then I should obtain the same starting value (float precision errors included).

I am sure about `Spherical.ToCartesian` implementation because when I test the values in keisan I obtain the same values.

Here is the `coordinate.go` file :

```golang
import (
    . "math"
)

/////////////
// Cartesian Coordinates
/////////////
type Cartesian struct {
    X float64 `json:"x"`
    Y float64 `json:"y"`
    Z float64 `json:"z"`
}

// func (c Cartesian) ToCartesian() Cartesian {...}

// Following : https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1359533867
func (c Cartesian) ToSpherical() Spherical{
    r := Sqrt(Pow(c.X, 2.) + Pow(c.Y, 2.) + Pow(c.Z, 2.))
    return Spherical{
        Latitude:  RadToDeg(Atan(Sqrt(c.X * c.X + c.Y * c.Y) / c.Z)),
        Longitude: RadToDeg(Atan2(c.Y, c.X)),
        Radius: r,
    }
}

// func (c Cartesian) ToPolar() Polar {...}

/////////////
// Spherical Coordinates
/////////////
type Spherical struct {
    Radius    float64 `json:"radius"`
    // Aka θ
    Longitude float64 `json:"longitude"`
    // Aka ϕ
    Latitude  float64 `json:"latitude"`
}

// Following : https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1359534351
func (g Spherical) ToCartesian() Cartesian {
    return Cartesian{
        // x = r * sin ϕ * cos θ
        X: g.Radius * Sin(DegToRad(g.Latitude)) * Cos(DegToRad(g.Longitude)),
        // y = r * sin ϕ * sin θ
        Y: g.Radius * Sin(DegToRad(g.Latitude)) * Sin(DegToRad(g.Longitude)),
        // z = r * cos ϕ
        Z: g.Radius * Cos(DegToRad(g.Latitude)),
    }
}
```

And here is the test that is not working :

```golang
var g = Spherical{
    Longitude: 200,
    Latitude:  100,
    Radius:    10000,
}

func TestSpherical_ToCartesianToSpherical(t *testing.T) {
    v := g.ToCartesian().ToSpherical()

    if !IsFloatEq(g.Radius, v.Radius) {
        t.Error("Bad Radius conversion. Expected", g.Radius, "got", v.Radius)
    }
    if !IsFloatEq(g.Longitude, v.Longitude) {
        t.Error("Bad Longitude conversion. Expected", g.Longitude, "got", v.Longitude)
    }
    if !IsFloatEq(g.Latitude, v.Latitude) {
        t.Error("Bad Latitude conversion. Expected", g.Latitude, "got", v.Latitude)
    }
}
```

When I `go test`, I obtain this :

```
--- FAIL: TestGeographic_ToCartesianToGeographic (0.00s)
    geographic_test.go:34: Bad Longitude conversion. Expected 200 got -160
    geographic_test.go:37: Bad Latitude conversion. Expected 100 got -80
FAIL
FAIL    common/coordinates      0.113s
FAIL
```

I really not see where is the problem.

Hope for any help :)

Comment: 200° and -160° are the same given that a circle has 360°. You could just add 360° if the result is negative.

Comment: On a side note, golang recommends against using "_" in the variable name. Go is an opinionated language, and there's a reason for that.

Comment: I feel stupid right now . But I don’t understand why -80 is a good value because of 360 - 80 = 280 and its the  exact opposite of 100 (I’m really bad in math).  Rafee I take that in note thanks

Comment: @rafee `_` in Golang has a meaning, I think your comment is missleading. Using `_` means that I won't be using that value (for example, when a function returns two values but you only want one of them). I'm not 100% certain if go compiler does some optimization based on this.

Comment: Add range checking. Lon should range between -180 and 180 and Lat between -90 to 90. You are inputting wrong values.

Comment: Every library I know uses radians for angles, not degrees.  That's true of Go as well: https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Cos

Comment: @Adirio I referred to variable name "TestSpherical_ToCartesianToSpherical"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spherical coordinates are represented by:

1. `r`: radius, which is the striaght distance from the origin.
2. `φ`: inclination or polar angle, which is the angle from the vertical axis Z.
3. `θ`: azimuth or azimuthal angle, which is the angle of the projected point into the XY plane from the X axis.

**NOTE1:** in physichs, the Greek letters used to represent both angles are swapped, but I will use this notation as it seems to be the one you are using based on your formulas.

**NOTE2:** there is another way of expressing inclination called elevation which is measured from the XY plane. `elevation = 90° - φ`.

**NOTE3:** in geography, the elevation is called latitude and the azimuth is called longitude.

The difference with cartesian coordinates, where each point has a single representation, is that the same point can be represented in different ways in spherical coordinates. The following transformations both create new points `P2 = {r2, φ2, θ2}` with different values from the original points `P1 = {r1, φ1, θ1}` but they are both the same point (`P2 == P1`) despite the values being different.

```
/ r2 = r1              / r2 = - r1
| φ2 = φ1              | φ2 = 180° - φ1
\ θ2 = θ1 + 360°       \ θ2 = θ1 + 180°
```

Which is the solution? Normalizing the spherical coordinates. The most common normalize system uses only positive radius values and limits the angles to 180° and 360°:

```
/ 0  <= r <  inf
| 0° <= φ <= 180°  -> which means -90° <= elevation <= 90°
\ 0° <= θ <  360°
```

The reasoning why the inclination is limited to 180° is because a higher inclination can be achieved by rotating 180° extra degrees in the azimuth angle and having a inclination lower than 180°.

So, in order to be able to compare values to check if they are the same point, you first need to normalize. Follow the following steps:

1. If `r = 0`: return `{0, 0°, 0°}` (if the radius is zero, angles don't change anything so return 0° angles)
2. If `r < 0`: `r = -r`, `φ = 180° - φ` and `θ += 180°`
3. While `φ >= 360°`: `φ -= 360°`
4. While `φ < 0°`: `φ += 360°`
5. If `φ = 0°` or `φ = 180°`: return `{r, φ, 0°}` (if the inclination is null or 180°, the point is in the vertical axis Z, so azimuth doesn't mean anything, use 0°)
6. If `φ > 180°`: `φ = 360° - φ` and `θ += 180°`
7. While `θ >= 360°`: `θ -= 360°`
8. While `θ < 0°`: `θ += 360°`
9. Return `{r, φ, θ}`

In geography, longitude is sometimes normalized to `-180° < θ <= 180°` which would modify step 7 and 8 to:

7. While `θ > 180°`: `θ -= 360°`
8. While `θ <= -180°`: `θ += 360°`

Here you have a [Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/nNCMfYUbXff) with the classes inplemented with normalize and conversion methods for `Cartesian`, `Spherical` and `Geograpical` (a `Spherical` but that its created from and prints latitude and longitude instead of inclination and azimuth).

Comment: I took the liberty of replacing º (U+00BA: MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR) by ° (U+00B0: DEGREE SIGN). This is indeed one of the most common mistakes in digital typography worldwide!